# How to convert Unix Timestamp to date with GMT (IST) format using moment in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    test:{"A":"\/Date(1442773800000+0530)\/","B":"423"}
```

Hi i am getting big trouble,Above is my data (JSON format), here i am using momentjs for convert Unix time stamp to date and time without using + 530 code, Sometime date not showing correct format, its automatically convert different UTC/GMT (time Zone),

```
 moment(test.A).format('DD-MM-YYYY  HH:mm')
```

how to use including the GMT(+530) in moment script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**utcOffset()** is the preferred method as of Moment 2.9.0. This function uses the real offset from UTC, not the reverse offset.

```
moment(1369266934311).utcOffset(+530).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

And if you are using Moment version less then 2.9. You can go with this :

```
moment(1369266934311).zone(+530).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

Comment: As a reminder: If you have to manipulate the offset manually in any language with any library you are probably using the wrong API. There are very few exceptions, where such a manipulation is a clever idea.